# mysql_fetch_assoc() returning single row even though there are many rows

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run this program but unexpectedly the mysql_fetch_assoc() function is returning only the first entry even though there are many entries and further more in foreach loop error say that illegal 'parameter' username is given

```
<?php
$dbc=mysql_connect("localhost","root","nanu");
mysql_select_db('users');
$getQuery='SELECT * FROM userst  ORDER BY username';
$result=mysql_query($getQuery,$dbc);
$rel=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo'<pre>'.print_r($rel).'<pre/>';
echo"<br/>".$rel['username']."<br/>";
foreach($rel as $Query[]){
echo $Query['username'];
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: -1 because you didn't read the manual. Or one of trillion tutorials.

Comment: Im still wondering on how hard did you try to trace the problem, probably the first google results  provides an example of the usage of the mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retuning an array or rows, you have to loop thru each row

```
while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo'<pre>'.print_r($rel).'<pre/>'; 
    echo"<br/>".$rel['username']."<br/>";
    foreach($rel as $Query[]){ //don't think you need this foreach loop
    echo $Query['username'];
    }
}
```

also [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) always returns the next row or false. You should call it in a loop:

```
while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {...}
```

Comment: shouldn't be mysql_ though (I know that's what the OP used)

Answer (score 1):

`$rel=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` will only fetch one row at a time depending on the resource pointer.

This pointer will increase once you use that statement, so using it with a loop statement will give you all the rows.

```
while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $rel['username'];
}
```

Please try more safer API's like `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` API. **They are deprecated.**

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

> It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns the row at the current pointer. You need to use it as part of a loop, as the PHP docs show:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['username'];
}
```